# ValueError: too many values to unpack Multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, json, multiprocessing

I have the following 'worker' that initially returned a single JSON object, but I would like it to return multiple JSON objects:

```
def data_worker(data):
    _cats, index, total = data
    _breeds = {}

    try:
        url = _channels['feedUrl']
        r = get(url, timeout=5)
        rss = etree.XML(r.content)

        tags = rss.xpath('//cats/item')
        _cats['breeds'] = {}
        for t in tags:
            _cats['breeds']["".join(t.xpath('breed/@url'))] = True 
            _breeds['url'] = "".join(t.xpath('breed/@url'))

        return [_cats, _breeds]
    except:
        return [_cats, _breeds]
```

This worker is a parameter for a multiprocessing pool:

```
cats, breeds = pool.map(data_worker, data, chunksize=1)
```

When I run the pool and the worker with just one output (i.e. _cats), it works just fine, but when I try to return multiple JSON "schemas," I get the error:

```
  File "crawl.py", line 111, in addFeedData
    [cats, breeds] = pool.map(data_worker, data, chunksize=1)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

**How can I return 2 separate JSON objects in data_worker?** I need them to be separate JSON objects. Note, I have already tried the following, which did not work:

```
[cats, breeds] = pool.map(data_worker, data, chunksize=1)
(cats, breeds) = pool.map(data_worker, data, chunksize=1)
return (_cats, _breeds)
```

Answer (score 8):

First of all I think you meant to write this:

```
cats, breeds = pool.map(data_worker, data, chunksize=1)
```

But anyway this won't work, because `data_worker` returns a pair, but `map()` returns a list of whatever the worker returns.  So you should do this:

```
cats = []
breeds = []
for cat, breed in pool.map(data_worker, data, chunksize=1):
    cats.append(cat)
    breeds.append(breed)
```

This will give you the two lists you seek.

In other words, you expected a pair of lists, but you got a list of pairs.