# Python: Too Many values to unpack on return

Tags: python

I hope, this is not a duplicate. I know what too many values to unpack means. I am returning two values, and trying to accept two values.

I am providing only a short part of the code, I hope it will be enough.

```
def test(all the arguments in function_parameters):
    // do something


    dfData.append([fileToCheck,5,";".join(faceNames),frameTime,";".join(faceDistances),";".join(faceLocations),";".join(gender),str(";".join(age)),str(";".join(expression))])

    if len(face_locations) != 0:
        keyPointsData.append([fileToCheck,time,str(";".join(encodings)),str(";".join(encodings)),time])
    else:
        keyPointsData.append([fileToCheck,time,"","",time])

    return dfData, keyPointsData

#Start multiprocessing
#Pass variables to the function
function_parameters = zip(
    images_to_check,
    itertools.repeat(known_names),
    itertools.repeat(known_face_encodings),
    itertools.repeat(tolerance),
    itertools.repeat(processImages),
    itertools.repeat(processVideos),
    itertools.repeat(fpstoprocess),
    itertools.repeat(upsample),
    itertools.repeat(algo),
    itertools.repeat(onlydetection),
    itertools.repeat(saveimagespath),
    itertools.repeat(savefullimages),
    itertools.repeat(savefaceimage),
    itertools.repeat(enablebox),
    itertools.repeat(maxarea),
    listNumber,
    itertools.repeat(totalImages),
    itertools.repeat(imageExtensions),
    itertools.repeat(videoExtensions),
    itertools.repeat(debug),
    itertools.repeat(age),
    itertools.repeat(gender),
    itertools.repeat(expression),
    itertools.repeat(keypointsDF)
)



rows,keypointsData =  pool.starmap(test, function_parameters)
```

`tdfData` and `keyPointsData` are multidimensional list. I am using Multi threads

I am getting error at this line `rows,keypointsData =  pool.starmap(test, function_parameters)`

Full Error Message

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "face.py", line 829, in <module>
    main()
  File "face.py", line 702, in main
    process_images_in_process_pool()
  File "face.py", line 584, in process_images_in_process_pool
    rows,keypointsData =  pool.starmap(test, function_parameters)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Can you share the complete trackback?

Comment: Okay. Editing the question

Comment: `pool.starmap(test(arguments), functional_parameters)`

Comment: Added more information. @beer44...Do you need more?

Comment: Yes, please also update the content of function parameter `function_parameters` you passing `pool.starmap(test, function_parameters)` ?. I think it here the issue

Comment: Done @beer44 ..

Comment: I tried the same function, without multiprocessing, and I am not getting any error.

Comment: I think this solution worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303117/valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-multiprocessing-pool

Comment: `test` eeturns 2 items, but that doesn't mean that `starmap` does.  During debugging it's a good idea to avoid `unpacking` until you know what's happening.

Comment: @JohnBott , I added the answer, hope it will helps you to use `starmap` functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap

starmap takes an iterator to call the function with different input from iterator and then return another iterator with all the output with their corresponding inputs.

So here take an example:

```
def test(a, b):
    return a, b
```

now calling the function with iterator of different input:

```
iter1 = zip([1, 2], [3, 4])
list_of_results = pool.starmap(test, iter1)

>>> list_of_results
>>> [(2, 3), (4, 5)]
x, y = pool.starmap(test, iter1) # unpacking will work
```

But in case of iterator call more times than 2 unpacking with 2 variables will fail:

```
iter2 = zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
list_of_results = pool.starmap(test, iter2)
>>> list_of_results
>>> [(2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 7)]
x, y = pool.starmap(test, iter1) # unpacking will fail
```

Therefore first store the result in `list_of_results` and then iterate over it to use the output values to avoid unpacking issue.

Hope it will clear the doubt and issue